# Android AlarmManager set function doesn't work?

Tags: android, alarm, alarmmanager

I want to add an alarm, so I used the following code:

```
    public void SetAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    mTimeTarget = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, alarm.getRowID(), 
            new Intent(HomeScreen.ACTION_CHECK_TIME_ALARMS), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, alarm.getAlarmTime().toMillis(true), mTimeTarget);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. (I tried on the emulator, and when the time
comes, nothing happens - my onReceive function on my class that extends BroadcastReceiver isn't called).

Here is how I initialized mAlarmManager on the constructor (it is private because this class is singleton):

```
    private AlarmsManager(Context con)
{
    mContext = con;

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `alarm.getAlarmTime().toMillis(true)` is not in the timebase of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. If `getAlarmTime()` returns a `android.text.format.Time` object, this is most certainly incorrect.

Comment: I have managed to fix this! The problem was in the time, as you said. Thank you very much!!!